# What is the difference between $\iff$ and $=$?

Tags: logic

If I say:

$$ x(x+1)(x-1) = x^3 -x $$

AND
$$ x(x+1)(x-1) \iff x^3 -x $$

What is the difference? Do they refer to the same thing? If not, what is valid to say, the first one or the second?

Comment: $\iff$ is for logical statements. You wouldn't say $2+2 \iff 4$. You would say $2+2 = 4 \iff$ ... idk, some other statement.

Comment: $=$ is used with *terms* (like 1+1, i.e. "names" for numbers, etc) while $\Leftrightarrow$ is used with *formulas* ("statements").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\iff$ is generally used as a logical operator "if and only if".  So you might say
$$ x (x+1)(x-1) = 3  \iff x^3 - x = 3 $$
because both sides are statements and they are logically equivalent.  But $x (x+1)(x-1)$ and $x^3 - x$ are not statements, so $\iff$ would not make sense for them.

Comment: so the idea is, an *entire equation* is a statement? so that we can join two equations by iff..?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A "statement" is something that can be true or false; "2" is neither true nor false, while 2+2=4 is true and 2+2=6 is false. The logical operator "$\iff$" is used to connect such statements, and produces a complex statement that is true exactly in those cases where the statements it connects are both true or both false.